# How do I prevent loading resources from both src/main/resources and src/test/resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have a spring boot app, with an H2 db. The app bootstraps the db on start up, and for this, I have a schema.sql / data.sql files in both src/main/resources and src/test/resources. When I run unit tests, each location is read and all the files are loaded, resulting in creating the DB twice. The test classpath is broader than it should. If I run the main app, I do not observe the problem. How do I force junit tests to only consider resources in the test folder ? Note that the problem is the same whether I run in eclipse or with maven.

[image: Project View]

This is what I see in the logs when I run a test

```
2019-12-17 15:34:25.549 :  Executing SQL script from URL [file:<REDACTED>/target/classes/schema.sql]
...
2019-12-17 15:34:25.601 :  Executed SQL script from URL [file:<REDACTED>/target/classes/schema.sql] in 52 ms.
2019-12-17 15:34:25.601 :  Executing SQL script from URL [file:<REDACTED>/target/test-classes/schema.sql]
...
2019-12-17 15:34:25.618 :  Executed SQL script from URL [file:<REDACTED>/target/test-classes/schema.sql] in 17 ms.
```

My tests start like this (removing @ComponentScan does not solve the problem):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@ComponentScan
public class SiteDaoTest {
...
}
```

The application.properties are vanilla

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

# spring.profiles.active=test
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=debug
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

I have experimented with profiles, which works to get around this issue, but this seems the wrong solution to me.

Comment: Assuming your schema.sql file in src/test/resources is a duplicate of  src/main/resources, you can just remove it from src/test/resources

Comment: To expand that comment a little; src/test/* is adding information to what already exists from the main application.  Tests run with all the configuration from src/main/*, *plus* all the classes/resources/etc from src/test/*

Comment: It is a duplicate at the moment, but will change in the future when I swap it for a better DB. Besides, the data.sql files are not duplicate, and this causes integrity violations.

Comment: You are getting this issue because you are running the application and trying to run tests on it. That would load regular properties. May be use profiles and run tests based on the profile and rename those files to indicate the profiles. that way only those files get loaded.https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/

Comment: I think you are both right guys. I misunderstood the default layout, thinking tests and core app would be completely independent. But by design, the configurations are chained when it comes to tests. My only option is to use profiles then. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @SandrewCheru: For the benefit of newbies, could you please share an example of the profiles you created for running tests using a separate config (application.properties, schema.sql and data.sql)?

Comment: Profiled properties is not the answer. Same thing happens when running test profile. The only option was to auto wire repo and add beforeAll to remove data form app side.